# Is it safe to send ajax post like this? If not, how to clean it?

Tags: python, ajax, django

All tutorias of how to use ajax with django said I should do something like this. But is that safe to do this? Cannot someone just change the values in the browser to some malicious SQL? If so, how to prevent it?

**javascript**

```
text = this.previousElementSibling.value;
parent = this.parentNode.id;

ajax.open('POST', '/post/comment/', true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4) {
        reply = document.createElement("DIV");
        reply.classList.add('post');
        reply.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById('comments').appendChild(reply);
    }
}
ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
ajax.send(JSON.stringify({'text': text,'parent': parent}));
```

**views.py**

```
def post_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        parent = Post.objects.get(pk=body['parent'])

        comment = Comment.objects.create(
            author=request.user,
            parent=parent,
            group=parent.group,
            text=body['text']
        )
```

Comment: not a js question, please remove tag.

Comment: `Cannot someone just change the values in the browser to some malicious SQL?` well, there is no SQL... although you are blindly inserting unsanitized HTML as HTML into the page.

Comment: The ORM should be tokenizing your input to block from SQL injection.  Most libraries have that built in unless you specifically call actual SQL code.